# vertical align in div gets ignored

Tags: css, html

I have the following div:

```
<div id="footer"> 
Copyright 2011 <a href="http://www.mauricederegt.com" target="_blank">mauricederegt.com</a> | <img src="images/facebookIconSmall.jpg" alt="" />
<a href="http://apps.facebook.com/mahjong_solitaire/" target="_blank">Facebook</a> | <img src="images/twitter.gif" alt="" />
<a href="https://twitter.com/mahjonggame" target="_blank">Twitter</a>
</div>
```

With this css:

```
#footer {
    position: relative; 
    z-index:999999; 
    width: 760px;
    /*height: 50px;*/
    top: 617px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    text-align: center;
    font-size:11px;
    display:table-cell;
}

#footer img {
    position:relative;
    bottom: -3px;
}
```

But when loading this one, the div's content isn't aligned in the middle, but at the bottom. What am I missing?

Comment: Do you want the text to line up with the center line of the images? As it is your footer object has no height specified so I would assume that's auto-sized.

Comment: `display: table-cell` will not work in all browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `vertical-align: middle;` to the img tags and the a tags then they will align.

I would also put the Copyright into a span tag and set vertical align that as well.

I put it all in a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qJk4s/

(You'll need to scroll down to see the footer though since you absolutely positioned it)

Answer (score 0):

It is aligned to the middle but you don't give it enough space that you notice the difference. Remove the comments to give the footer some height and you'll see the text is in the middle and the image is, appropriately, 3px off the bottom IF you remove the 'display:table-cell' which I have no clue why that is there or needed.